# Get data item value dynamically in Kentico Text/XML Transformation

Tags: kentico

I have a custom macro method that returns a string array of field names whose values I want to output in a Text/XML transformation. The transformation is being used as the Item Template in a Datalist. I cannot figure out though how to dynamically get the value from the current data item. It seems that `DataItem` does not resolve -- nothing outputs from the `GetValue` call below. Using `CurrentDocument` would obviously resolve the page instead of the data item.

```
<tr>
  <td>{% SKUNumber %}</td>
  {% foreach (spec in Util.GetSpecFieldsForPageType(CurrentDocument.NodeClass, "RelatedModelsTable")) {  %}
    <td class="hidden-xs">{% GetValue(DataItem, spec) %} </td>
  {% } #%}
</tr>
```

Is there any way to access the current data item in a Text/XML transformation? Or do I need to switch to an ASCX transform?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you're using Kentico v10, you're looking for the `Object` macro.

Using an indexer, you can specify a column to retrieve data from:

```
{% Object[columnName] %}
```

In your case, it would be:

```asp
<tr>
  <td>{% SKUNumber %}</td>
  {% foreach (spec in Util.GetSpecFieldsForPageType(CurrentDocument.NodeClass, "RelatedModelsTable")) { %}
    <td class="hidden-xs">{% Object[spec] %}</td>
  {% } #%}
</tr>
```

Here's a generic example, for those who need an example without any custom macros. This will dynamically render `DocumentID`, `DocumentName` and `NodeAliasPath`, specifying the columns in an array, as opposed to hardcoding them.

```asp
<tr>
  {% columns = "DocumentID,DocumentName,NodeAliasPath"; foreach (column in columns.Split(",")) {  %}
  <td>{% Object[column] %} </td>
  {% } #%}
</tr>
```

**EDIT:**

As Kentico v9 does not have the `Object` macro for transformations, one way to dynamically resolve a value of the repeated item is to use `Util.ResolveMacroExpession`, and supply the column name as the parameter.

The repeated item fields are registered as [named sources](https://docs.kentico.com/k9/macro-expressions/extending-the-macro-engine/adding-custom-macro-fields#Addingcustommacrofields-Namedsources), so there is no way to access them with an indexer or macro method.

Here's the same example from the question author, modified to work in Kentico v9:

```asp
<tr>
  <td>{% SKUNumber %}</td>
  {% foreach (spec in Util.GetSpecFieldsForPageType(CurrentDocument.NodeClass, "RelatedModelsTable")) { %}
    <td class="hidden-xs">{% Util.ResolveMacroExpression(spec) %}</td>
  {% } #%}
</tr>
```

Comment: I have updated my answer with a solution for Kentico 9

Comment: Fixed typo in ResolveMacroExpression but otherwise that was exactly what I needed. Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have to give us the scenario to get the right answer

If your {% Util.GetSpecFieldsForPageType(CurrentDocument.NodeClass, "RelatedModelsTable")%} returns IEnumbrable you can use [ApplyTransformation](https://docs.kentico.com/k81/developing-websites/loading-and-displaying-data-on-websites/writing-transformations/using-transformations-in-macro-expressions)

Comment: It's outputting an array of column/fields names that I want to write out from the data source item.

Comment: ApplyTransfornation doesn't help me, unless I'm missing something. I just want to output the value of the field.